# Using cauchy integral for a gamma path. Is the integration done correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Given the following integral of gamma on the path for the circle $[0,2]$ and circle $[-2,2]$. Where 0 is the center and 2 is the radius as well for the 2nd circle 0,-2 is the center and 2 is the radius. we have the integral
 $$ \int_\gamma \frac{z} {(z^2-1)(z-3)}dz$$

I set it up like

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-3)}}{z-1}=2\pi i $$

and i get that =

$$ \frac{-\pi i}{2} $$

and then i did the following for $[-2,2]$ but i dont believe they are set up correctly and was wondering if i can have some guidance or the error pointed out

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{\frac{z}{(z^2-1)}}{z-3}=2\pi i $$

then after everything i get its = 0 or pi i/4

Comment: What do you mean by the "path" $[-2,2]$ or the "path" $[0,2]$?

Comment: The gamma path on the circle [-2,2], I apologize

Comment: What do you mean by "circle [-2. 2]"? One would traditionally specify a circle by its centre and radius.

Comment: The poles of the integrand are at $z=-1$, $z=1$, and $z=3$.  Which poles are enclosed?  Have you thought of using partial fraction expansion?